# TSQL Select query that generates output similar to the ms access multiple value fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables in SQL Server 2008 such as:

TopicTable

```
 TopicID: nvarchar  (Primary Key)
 ProgID: nvarchar
 topic1: bit
 topic2: bit
 topic3: bit
 topic4: bit
```

The topic table looks something like the following:

```
 TopicID      ProgID        topic1        topic2       topic3        topic4

 topic001     prog001         1             1             0             0
 topic002     prog002         1             0             1             1
 topic003     prog003         1             0             0             0
 topic004     prog004         1             1             1             1
```

Program table:

```
 ProgID: nvarchar  (Primary Key)
 ProgramName: nvarchar
```

The Program table looks like this:

```
 ProgID         ProgramName         

 prog001        programA            
 prog002        programB
 prog003        programC
 prog004        programD
```

I want to create a view to get the output like:

```
   ProgID         ProgramName          Topic

   prog001        programA             topic1,topic2
   prog002        programB             topic1,topic3,topic4
   prog003        programB             topic1
   prog004        programD             topic1,topic2,topic3,topic4
```

Please can someone help me how to get this.
Thank You.

Comment: Show some data and expected output.

Comment: Take a look here: http://codecorner.galanter.net/2009/06/25/t-sql-string-aggregate-in-sql-server/

Comment: @YuriyGalanter. That link was good but, its not exactly what I am looking for. I want the column names to be returned as column values and then have them aggregated for each ProgID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have some extra commas here but you can tweak the code a little bit more to eliminate the extra commas . this is what I have got for you so far

```
CREATE Table Topic (Topic NVARCHAR(20), Programe NVARCHAR(20), Topic1 bit, Topic2 bit,Topic3 bit,Topic4 bit)
GO
INSERT INTO Topic
 VALUES 
 ('topic001','prog001',1,1,0,0),
 ('topic002','prog002',1,0,1,1),
 ('topic003','prog003',1,0,0,0),
 ('topic004','prog004',1,1,1,1)
 GO


CREATE TABLE Programe (P_ID NVARCHAR(20) , Name NVARCHAR(20))
GO
INSERT INTO Programe VALUES
 ('prog001','programA'),            
 ('prog002','programB'),
 ('prog003','programC'),
 ('prog004','programD')
 GO
```

**View Definition**

```
CREATE VIEW vw_ViewName
AS
 SELECT P_ID, Name, ISNULL(STUFF(L1.Topic1L, 1, 1 , '') + ', ', '') + ISNULL(STUFF(L2.Topic2L, 1, 1, '') + ', ', '') 
                                    +  ISNULL( STUFF(L3.Topic3L, 1, 1, '')+ ', ', '') + ISNULL(STUFF(L4.Topic4L, 1, 1, '')+ ', ', '')  AS Topics
 FROM Programe P CROSS APPLY (
                            SELECT ' ' + CASE WHEN Topic1 = 1 THEN 'Topic1' ELSE NULL END [text()]
                            FROM Topic
                            WHERE Programe = P.P_ID
                            FOR XML PATH('')
                            )L1(Topic1L)
                CROSS APPLY (
                            SELECT ', ' + CASE WHEN Topic2 = 1 THEN 'Topic2' ELSE NULL END [text()]
                            FROM Topic
                            WHERE Programe = P.P_ID
                            FOR XML PATH('')
                            )L2(Topic2L)
               CROSS APPLY (
                            SELECT ', ' + CASE WHEN Topic3 = 1 THEN 'Topic3' ELSE NULL END [text()]
                            FROM Topic
                            WHERE Programe = P.P_ID
                            FOR XML PATH('')
                            )L3(Topic3L)
               CROSS APPLY (
                            SELECT ', ' + CASE WHEN Topic4= 1 THEN 'Topic4' ELSE NULL END [text()]
                            FROM Topic
                            WHERE Programe = P.P_ID
                            FOR XML PATH('')
                            )L4(Topic4L)
```

**RESULT SET**

```
P_ID    Name        Topics
prog001 programA    Topic1,  Topic2, 
prog002 programB    Topic1,  Topic3,  Topic4, 
prog003 programC    Topic1, 
prog004 programD    Topic1,  Topic2,  Topic3,  Topic4,
```

Comment: The view works exactly as I wanted, but I get this syntax error message every time I open the view design. The error message says: Error in WHERE clause near '('. Unable to parse query text. It goes away when I click the OK button and it executes with out any problem. I cant figure out why is this error message popping up. Is it because of (Topic1L), (Topic2L), (Topic3L), (Topic4L).

Comment: I Created the tables and then executed the view statement and it works fine. Check your syntax carefully maybe when you are replacing tables names in this query with the actually table names you are missing something.

Comment: If you create the tables I have created in my answer and then wxecute the query it throws no error, It means the syntax is correct. Just read the code carefully and try to follow the logic, im sure it will work :)

Comment: When executing as a view I get the error message but when executing as a query I donot get any error messages. The query design does not show any errors in the query. I tried the answer given by David and I get the same error message. Is it something to do with the PATH('') command. The view runs perfectly but I am just curious to know why I get the error message every time I open the view in design mode.

Comment: I have just created a view and selected data from it, its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

It would look like this:

```
;WITH cteTopics AS (
SELECT T.ProgID
  ,STUFF((
    SELECT T1.TopicID + ','
    FROM TopicTable T1
    WHERE T1.ProgID = T.ProgID
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR (MAX)')
    ,1,0,'') [Topics]
FROM TopicTable T
GROUP BY T.ProgID)

SELECT P.ProgID, P.ProgramName, T.Topics
FROM Program P
LEFT JOIN cteTopics T ON T.ProgID = P.ProgID
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9e4a/4